# Why does rvm switch gemsets when I cd into my rails project directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

For what possible reason would rvm switch gemsets when I cd into my rails project directory?

I don't have an .rvmrc file. I set a default gemset (which "sticks" for other directories). Here's what I mean:

```
[20130109_234306] will@localhost:~
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p362 (found in /Users/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362)
   (default)
   global
=> ruby-1.9.3

[20130109_234313] will@localhost:~
$ cd Projects/rails_project

[20130109_234320] will@localhost:~/Projects/rails_project
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p362 (found in /Users/will/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362)
=> (default)
   global
   ruby-1.9.3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gemfile in the rails project directory will tell RVM to switch rubies if the Gemfile specifies a ruby version (something like ruby="1.9.3" or #ruby=1.9.3@gemset).

This is because RVM supports more then just `.rvmrc` => https://rvm.io/workflow/projects/#ruby-versions a full list can be found here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/functions/rvmrc#L743-L744

Note that RVM will check the following files *before* the Gemfile: `.rvmrc` `.versions.conf` `.ruby-version` `.rbfu-version` `.rbenv-version`. So creating a `.rvmrc` file with the line "`rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p362@ruby-1.9.3`" would make RVM ignore the Gemfile.

Comment: It looks like rvm checks the Gemfile (`"$path_to_check/Gemfile"`) -- could that cause rvm to switch gemsets?

Comment: yes `Gemfile` if has a line `ruby="1.9.3"` or `#ruby=1.9.3@gemset` would make RVM switch gemsets/rubies

Comment: Is an .rvmrc file the preferred way to tell rvm to ignore the Gemfile?

Comment: any file that is checked before `Gemfile` would do: `.rvmrc` `.versions.conf` `.ruby-version` `.rbfu-version` `.rbenv-version`

Answer (score 1):

RVM has a feature called [Project .rvmrc](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/). In `~/Projects/rails_project` there is a file called `.rvmrc`, which contains instructions for RVM for when you move into that project.

**Edit**: I missed the line about you not having that file. Sorry.

Comment: I added a .rvmrc file *just* before I read your answer -- and it makes everything work. :) But I'm still confused as to why I need it at all...

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the project .rvmrc which disables project Gemfile checking as well. To do this, add the following line to `/etc/rvmrc` or `~/.rvmrc`. Then you wont have to add a .rvmrc file to any project, as they will be ignored with the Gemfile. This was tested on rvm `1.19.6 (Stable)`.

```
rvm_project_rvmrc=0
```

Source: https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc

Answer (score 0):

have two way at least to achieve this, eg：

1. `echo 2.1.1 > .ruby-version` and `echo rails4 > .ruby-gemset`
2. add first line  `#ruby=2.1.1@rails4` to Gemfile

> why `.ruby-gemset` ?
>
> `.ruby-version` also supports gemsets in the form of `ruby@gemset` but this is not compatible with other Ruby Versions Managers. Another file might be used to specify the gemset without breaking compatibility - `.ruby-gemset`.

I think above is the best practice .